# MySQL multiple count in single query

Tags: mysql

I have a table named 'sales' with following fields

```
salesid (type: int)
stime (type: datetime)
status (type: enum, values: remaining OR cancelled OR done)
... and other fields
```

I need a query that can output as

```
SalesDate     TotalSales    TotalDone      TotalRemaining     TotalCancelled
2010-11-06       10             5                3                 2
2010-11-06       15             14                1                 0
```

Anyone know how to achieve this?
Help appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `CASE` statement in your `SELECT` to create pseudo columns using the status values of `remaining, cancelled` and `done`

```
SELECT     
     date(stime),
     COUNT(salesid),
     SUM(CASE status WHEN 'done' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as TotalDone,
     SUM(CASE status WHEN 'remaining' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as TotalRemaining, 
     SUM(CASE status WHEN 'cancelled' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as TotalCancelled 
FROM  sales
GROUP BY date(stime)
```

Note: This is what i was trying to refer to. I think this should work but i have no access to MySQL to try out the syntax and verify it. Sorry about that. But this should get you going.

Answer (score 3):

You can use conditional summation to get the results you want.

```
select stime  as sales_date
      ,sum(1) as total_sales
      ,sum(case when status = 'remaining' then 1 else 0 end) as total_done
      ,sum(case when status = 'cancelled' then 1 else 0 end) as total_remaining
      ,sum(case when status = 'done'      then 1 else 0 end) as total_cancelled
  from sales
 group by stime;
```

You can also use COUNT(*expr*) and exploit the fact it doesn't include NULLS, but personally I find that the above best conveys the intent of the developer.